# Can someone explain a range inside of a range?

Tags: python

I don't really have a "problem" with the code. It's more that I don't understand how it works. It's like...an nested if-statement, except this is a for statement nested inside a for-loop. Can some help me understand a bit more?

I googled some stuff about ranges in python, but didn't see anything like this one.

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        print(i, j)
```

There isn't an error message, because nothing is wrong with the code. I understand that the first part is saying the range for i is going to be 0, 1, & 2. Then for the second one, it's going to be 0 and 1. But how does that match up to all the ordered pairs? I'm sorry, I'm a noob, please forgive me.

Comment: Try running it and see what happens :)

Comment: maybe add `print("i=", i)` between both `for` and you will see how it works.

Comment: The *inner* loop starts and runs to exhaustion for each iteration of the outer loop. - Use http://www.pythontutor.com/ to visualize the execution.

Comment: Sometimes an odometer is used as an analogy for nested loops. The tens digit/wheel revolves once for every ten revolutions of the ones digit/wheel. The tens digit is the outer loop (`for i in...`) and the ones digit is the inner loop (`for j in ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        print('i: ',i, 'j: ',j)
        print('_'*20)
```

Output:

```
i:  0 j:  0
____________________
i:  0 j:  1
____________________
i:  1 j:  0
____________________
i:  1 j:  1
____________________
i:  2 j:  0
____________________
i:  2 j:  1
____________________
```

If you look `i = 0` it is selected in the first three print. This is because for `i = 0` the block of sentences from inside is executed. Since this block of sentences is another loop `for`, then for `i = 0`, the entire internal loop `for` is executed, that is, `j = 0` and `j = 1`. when this is over, it is executed again for `i = 1`.

Maybe you could understand it better like this:

```
list1=['hello','what is your name?:']
list2=['anne','mark']

for key in list1:
    for key2 in list2:
        print(key + ' ' +key2)
```

**Output:**

```
hello anne
hello mark
what is your name?: anne
what is your name?: mark
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add `print("i=", i)` between both `for` and you will see how it works.

First external `for` sets only `i=0` and it runs internal `for` with `j=0`, `j=1`, so you get `(0,0), (0,1)`.

After that it goes back to external loop which sets `i=1` and runs internal `for` again with `j=0`, `j=1` so you get `(1,0),(1,1)`.

After that it goes back to external loop which sets `i=2` and runs internal `for` again with `j=0`, `j=1` so you get `(2,0),(2,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to the party:

But you can consider `i,j` to be `row,col` and hence:

```
[[1,2,3],

[4,5,6],

[7,8,9]]
```

Running your code with these specific bounds will yield all values i.e. 1 2 3 ... 9.

If we consider the literal values of `i,j / row, col` then its just every combination of row and column.

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        print(i, j)
```

~~ =

```
for row in range(2):
    for col in range(2):
        print(i, j)
       #print(matrix[row][col])
```